# Elements of the Web Suddenly Disappear

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I wanted to paste the html code for creating a button into main index.html file after a specific line. Although I tried that. it would output the button but my homepage of the webpage would suddenly disappear, I do not know why.

This is the HTML and CSS code of the button:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta:700");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Mukta", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #f3f8fa;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
}

button.learn-more {
  width: 12rem;
  height: auto;
}

button.learn-more .circle {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: relative;
  right: 25px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background: #282936;
  border-radius: 1.625rem;
}

button.learn-more .circle .icon {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
}

button.learn-more .circle .icon.arrow {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  left: 0.625rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 0.125rem;
  background: none;
}

button.learn-more .circle .icon.arrow::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -0.25rem;
  right: 0.0625rem;
  width: 0.625rem;
  height: 0.625rem;
  border-top: 0.125rem solid #fff;
  border-right: 0.125rem solid #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

button.learn-more .button-text {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 1.85rem;
  color: #282936;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.6;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

button:hover .circle {
  width: 125%;
}

button:hover .circle .icon.arrow {
  background: #fff;
  transform: translate(1rem, 0);
}

button:hover .button-text {
  color: #fff;
}

@supports (display: grid) {
  body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 0.625rem;
    grid-template-areas: ". main main ." ". main main .";
  }
  #yes {
    grid-area: main;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/button.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="yes">
  <button class="learn-more">
        <span class="circle" aria-hidden="true">
          <span class="icon arrow"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="button-text">Check Out My Blogs!</span>
      </button>
</div>
```

I used the above code from different source, and now I want to paste the above code in my main index.html file which is this:

I would like the html code of the button to be displayed right after when it says, "This is my new favourite thing to do when I am bored:) You may wonder...." which is located near the very bottom if you scroll my main index.html file. I tried putting the html code after the line myself but like I said, the button dislays but my homepage or the "hero" section (located near the top) of the website disappears. Could you guys please help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <title>Hussain Omer</title>
  <meta content="" name="descriptison">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">
  <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-180664536-1">
  </script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-180664536-1');
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- ======= Mobile nav toggle button ======= -->

  <!-- ======= Header ======= -->
  <header id="header" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">

    <nav class="nav-menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#hero"><i class="bx bx-home"></i> <span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#about"><i class="bx bx-user"></i> <span>About Me</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#resume"><i class="bx bx-file-blank"></i> <span>Resume</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio"><i class="bx bx-book-content"></i> <span>Projects</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#services"><i class="bx bx-server"></i> <span>Blogs</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#services"><i class="bx bx-server"></i> <span>Skills</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"><i class="bx bx-envelope"></i> <span>Contact</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- .nav-menu -->

  </header>
  <!-- End Header -->

  <!-- ======= Hero Section ======= -->
  <section id="hero" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
    <div class="container" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
      <h1>Hussain Omer</h1>
      <p>I'm a <span class="typed" data-typed-items="Coder, Leader, Team-Player, Blog Writer, Adventurer"></span></p>
      <div class="social-links">
        <!--<a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="bx bxl-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="bx bxl-facebook"></i></a>-->
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kaustubh-prabhakar/" class="linkedin"><i class="bx bxl-linkedin"></i></a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://github.com/SantaKaus" class="github"><i class="bx bxl-github"></i></a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.instagram.com/h.s.z_11/" class="instagram"><i class="bx bxl-instagram"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- End Hero -->

  <main id="main">

    <!-- ======= About Section ======= -->
    <section id="about" class="about portfolio services">
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

        <div class="section-title">
          <h2>My Story</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row portfolio-container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Lahore, Pakistan (2003-2010)</h4>
                <p>I was born in Lahore, the second largest city of Pakistan. This is where I did most of my education and developed many memories. I enjoyed the very bit of the city; from the diverse culture and to the beautiful greenary. I haven't visited
                  Pakistan in over 5 years, and I hope to go back some day &#128512;
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-3.jpg" class="img-fluid">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Helsinki, Finland (2007-2010)</h4>
                <p>From a very unique and enjoyable Finnish school syst
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Helsinki, Finland (2007-2010)</h4>
                <p>From a very unique and enjoyable Finnish school syst

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="section-title">
        <h2>About ME</h2>
        <p>I am a 17 year old with a enthusiastic drive to working with technology, and using my prowess in Computers to make a positive impact on this world. </p>
      </div>
      <img src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1?ui=2&ik=79098a413c&attid=0.1&permmsgid=msg-f:1687893372595235455&th=176c9a145c466a7f&view=att&disp=safe&realattid=176c9a0f10e523984941" align="left" width="370" height="500">

      <!-- <div style="display:inline-block;"> to put text under something or start new -->
      <div class="aligned">
        <div class="p">
          <p>Motivated by my love for numbers, I started to explore the many ways I can use my Mathematical knowledge and implement it into different areas. I was introduced to Computer Science in my junior years of high school, and I came to know that I
            was genuinely passionated about learning it. It offers a holistic approach to solve problems which I admire, and since then, I have transformed my interest into a personal hobby!</p>
          <p>I would always like to challenge myself and learn new programming langauges to increase the size of my toolbox. I was inspired by one of my friends to take my programming skills and put it into a good use; thus, I was introduced to competitive
            programming and large coding events such as hackathons!</p>
          <p>The intellectual challenges, creativity, and logic programming offers has always further strengthened the inevitable bond between us.</p>
          <p>Challenging myself allows me to not only grow outside my comfort zone, but gives a new perspective towards life, and how there is no limitations/boundaries that halt you from growing! It is everlasting. Once you develop the growth mindset, your
            journey just never comes to a complete stop! You keep on growing outside your comfort zone, and being able to easily push through any obstacles.</p>
          <blockquote>
            Nothing Is Impossible. The Word Itself Says 'IM Possible'
            <cite>Audrey Hepburn</cite>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End About Section -->

    <!-- ======= Facts Section ======= -->
    <section id="facts" class="facts">
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

        <div class="section-title">
          <h2>What I am upto &#128515;</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 icon-box" data-aos="fade-up">
            <h4 class="title">7CUPS.com</h4>
            <p class="description">I am currently on the pursuit to make a positive impact on the world. To do this, I started volunteering with 7Cups as a trained listener to support people having emotional distress by interacting with them and resolving any concerns they
              might have. Especially in these unprecendented times (a.k.a when COVID hit), it is important to guide and support the ones that require additional assistance</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 icon-box" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
            <h4 class="title">School Clubs</h4>
            <p class="description">Being part of school clubs is personally my favourite thing:) Interacting with people, coming up with ideas and implementing it with various activities is a fun on its own! I am currently an active member of over 5 clubs and hold some executive
              positions. I'am the Vice-President of my school's STEM Club while also being the Technical Team Member for our school's Student Tech Hub</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 icon-box" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
            <h4 class="title">Blog Writing</h4>
            <p class="description">This is my new favourite thing to do when I am bored:) You may wonder what kind of blogs I write and specifically about what genre I write about. The answer is everything! I write about what is on my mind, and what I learn from my experiences.
              Basically self-reflections. I also tend to give general advices to people through my blogs!</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
    <!-- End Facts Section -->
```

This HTML code above is not my whole index.html, because my file is really long and it would be hard and confusing at the same time to locate the line

Comment: did you copy the link-tag right into the html? you have to copy that into your head tag, also the script tag needs to be at the right position in your html code

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I am doing wrong! If possible could you show me because someone else also suggested that, but I may be still putting in the wrong position

Comment: Update: I tried it again but it still doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the Code with the new snippet, the link and the script. I left comments on the far left starting with EDITED so you can find where. All you need to do now is create the CSS-Stylesheet that is mentioned in the link in the right folder and you should be good to go.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <title>Hussain Omer</title>
  <meta content="" name="descriptison">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">
  <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--EDITED: new link!-->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/button.css" />
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-180664536-1">
  </script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-180664536-1');
  </script>

</head>

<body>
<!--EDITED: new Script-->  
  <script async src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- ======= Mobile nav toggle button ======= -->

  <!-- ======= Header ======= -->
  <header id="header" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">

    <nav class="nav-menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#hero"><i class="bx bx-home"></i> <span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#about"><i class="bx bx-user"></i> <span>About Me</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#resume"><i class="bx bx-file-blank"></i> <span>Resume</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio"><i class="bx bx-book-content"></i> <span>Projects</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#services"><i class="bx bx-server"></i> <span>Blogs</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#services"><i class="bx bx-server"></i> <span>Skills</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"><i class="bx bx-envelope"></i> <span>Contact</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- .nav-menu -->

  </header>
  <!-- End Header -->

  <!-- ======= Hero Section ======= -->
  <section id="hero" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
    <div class="container" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
      <h1>Hussain Omer</h1>
      <p>I'm a <span class="typed" data-typed-items="Coder, Leader, Team-Player, Blog Writer, Adventurer"></span></p>
      <div class="social-links">
        <!--<a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="bx bxl-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="bx bxl-facebook"></i></a>-->
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kaustubh-prabhakar/" class="linkedin"><i class="bx bxl-linkedin"></i></a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://github.com/SantaKaus" class="github"><i class="bx bxl-github"></i></a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.instagram.com/h.s.z_11/" class="instagram"><i class="bx bxl-instagram"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- End Hero -->

  <main id="main">

    <!-- ======= About Section ======= -->
    <section id="about" class="about portfolio services">
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

        <div class="section-title">
          <h2>My Story</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row portfolio-container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Lahore, Pakistan (2003-2010)</h4>
                <p>I was born in Lahore, the second largest city of Pakistan. This is where I did most of my education and developed many memories. I enjoyed the very bit of the city; from the diverse culture and to the beautiful greenary. I haven't visited
                  Pakistan in over 5 years, and I hope to go back some day &#128512;
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-3.jpg" class="img-fluid">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Helsinki, Finland (2007-2010)</h4>
                <p>From a very unique and enjoyable Finnish school syst
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Helsinki, Finland (2007-2010)</h4>
                <p>From a very unique and enjoyable Finnish school syst

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="section-title">
        <h2>About ME</h2>
        <p>I am a 17 year old with a enthusiastic drive to working with technology, and using my prowess in Computers to make a positive impact on this world. </p>
      </div>
      <img src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1?ui=2&ik=79098a413c&attid=0.1&permmsgid=msg-f:1687893372595235455&th=176c9a145c466a7f&view=att&disp=safe&realattid=176c9a0f10e523984941" align="left" width="370" height="500">

      <!-- <div style="display:inline-block;"> to put text under something or start new -->
      <div class="aligned">
        <div class="p">
          <p>Motivated by my love for numbers, I started to explore the many ways I can use my Mathematical knowledge and implement it into different areas. I was introduced to Computer Science in my junior years of high school, and I came to know that I
            was genuinely passionated about learning it. It offers a holistic approach to solve problems which I admire, and since then, I have transformed my interest into a personal hobby!</p>
          <p>I would always like to challenge myself and learn new programming langauges to increase the size of my toolbox. I was inspired by one of my friends to take my programming skills and put it into a good use; thus, I was introduced to competitive
            programming and large coding events such as hackathons!</p>
          <p>The intellectual challenges, creativity, and logic programming offers has always further strengthened the inevitable bond between us.</p>
          <p>Challenging myself allows me to not only grow outside my comfort zone, but gives a new perspective towards life, and how there is no limitations/boundaries that halt you from growing! It is everlasting. Once you develop the growth mindset, your
            journey just never comes to a complete stop! You keep on growing outside your comfort zone, and being able to easily push through any obstacles.</p>
          <blockquote>
            Nothing Is Impossible. The Word Itself Says 'IM Possible'
            <cite>Audrey Hepburn</cite>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End About Section -->

    <!-- ======= Facts Section ======= -->
    <section id="facts" class="facts">
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

        <div class="section-title">
          <h2>What I am upto &#128515;</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 icon-box" data-aos="fade-up">
            <h4 class="title">7CUPS.com</h4>
            <p class="description">I am currently on the pursuit to make a positive impact on the world. To do this, I started volunteering with 7Cups as a trained listener to support people having emotional distress by interacting with them and resolving any concerns they
              might have. Especially in these unprecendented times (a.k.a when COVID hit), it is important to guide and support the ones that require additional assistance</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 icon-box" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
            <h4 class="title">School Clubs</h4>
            <p class="description">Being part of school clubs is personally my favourite thing:) Interacting with people, coming up with ideas and implementing it with various activities is a fun on its own! I am currently an active member of over 5 clubs and hold some executive
              positions. I'am the Vice-President of my school's STEM Club while also being the Technical Team Member for our school's Student Tech Hub</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 icon-box" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
            <h4 class="title">Blog Writing</h4>
            <p class="description">This is my new favourite thing to do when I am bored:) You may wonder what kind of blogs I write and specifically about what genre I write about. The answer is everything! I write about what is on my mind, and what I learn from my experiences.
              Basically self-reflections. I also tend to give general advices to people through my blogs!</p>

          </div>
<!--EDITED: new Part!-->          
          <div id="yes">
            <button class="learn-more">
                  <span class="circle" aria-hidden="true">
                    <span class="icon arrow"></span>
                  </span>
                  <span class="button-text">Check Out My Blogs!</span>
                </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
    <!-- End Facts Section -->
```

Comment: Nothing changed the button output but various parts of my website like pictures and home page section disappear

Comment: could it be that some rules in the CSS for the button override / collide with rules you set in your main stylesheet already?

Comment: Nope, I renamed some rules too but it still doesnt work

Comment: and if you remove the link to the new stylesheet does everything work again as before?

Comment: I renamed everything in my button.css and now it seems to work lmao

Comment: Alright, sometimes CSS is a little strange hehe. No Problem!